# check if the series $1/\log(\log(n))$ converge or diverge.

Tags: calculus

check if the series converge or diverge:

$$\frac{1}{\log \log n}$$

I tried to use comparison test but the limit was not finite
then i tried to use Cauchy Integral test for convergence but the integral not possible
similarly ratio test and root test were were difficult to use

Comment: Does this series start from $n=0$ or $n=1$?

Comment: Do you want to know whether the series converges or whether the sum of the series converges?

Comment: @aleden Is that a trick question (since the initial term could be ill-defined in either case)?

Comment: @madprob You mean whether the _sequence_ converges? Yes, that is another interpretation of the question; the English word _series_ could be a mistranslation from another language.

Comment: Anyway... clearly a homework question with the answer neatly written for him below.

Comment: @madprob Yes, except if this is to be interpreted as $$\lim_{n\to+\infty} \frac{1}{\log\log n}$$ which neither of the current answers covers.

Comment: $$\frac{1}{\log\log n}$$ is not a series. $$\sum_{n\geq 2}\frac{1}{\log\log n}$$ is a series, and it is trivially diverging.

Answer (score 2):

The series diverges for the comparison test

$\log\log n < n$ therefore $\dfrac{1}{\log\log n}>\dfrac{1}{n}$

harmonic series diverges so does the given series

Answer (score 1):

log log n < log n < n

so 1/(log log n) > (1/n)

$\sum \frac {1}{n}$ diverges by p-test and so given series diverges